# How upgrade transferred app in App Store? changed application-identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

We transferred an app from one App Store account to another, months ago. We had no issue upgrading the app, until now. In fact, the old TeamId is no more available since last week (the account was closed).

As a consequence the application-identifier is changed. In fact, it is `<TeamId>.<app-bundle>` and the old TeamId is no more available. As a consequence it is no more possible to upgrade the installed apps.

We can publish the app, but the installed app are not upgraded. In fact, the Store let users download the app as un upgrade, but at the end the button doesn't became "Open"; moreover, tha app icon gains the blue dot, but it is not updated.

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: If you have transferred the app then you should publish the update with your new team id. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the answer, to be more clear.

Comment: If the app was transferred then the App Store should handle the change in team id for you.  Make sure users are upgrading over an App Store install and not an older TestFlight or developer build.